# Java Recursion Wordbreak

Tags: java, recursion, dictionary

I'm trying to solve the following problem on Leetcode.

"Given a string s and a dictionary of words dict, determine if s can be segmented into a space-separated sequence of one or more dictionary words.

For example, given

```
s = "leetcode",
dict = ["leet", "code"].
```

Return true because "leetcode" can be segmented as "leet code".

Right now, 22 of the 23 tests past. Please help me locate the problem.

```
public class Solution {
public boolean wordBreak(String s, Set<String> dict) {
    if(dict.contains(s) ){
        return true;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i< s.length(); i++){
        if(dict.contains(s.substring(0, i))){
            return wordBreak(s.substring(i), dict);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Failing test:

"fohhemkkaecojceoaejkkoedkofhmohkcjmkggcmnami", ["kfomka","hecagbngambii","anobmnikj","c","nnkmfelneemfgcl","ah","bgomgohl","lcbjbg","ebjfoiddndih","hjknoamjbfhckb","eioldlijmmla","nbekmcnakif","fgahmihodolmhbi","gnjfe","hk","b","jbfgm","ecojceoaejkkoed","cemodhmbcmgl","j","gdcnjj","kolaijoicbc","liibjjcini","lmbenj","eklingemgdjncaa","m","hkh","fblb","fk","nnfkfanaga","eldjml","iejn","gbmjfdooeeko","jafogijka","ngnfggojmhclkjd","bfagnfclg","imkeobcdidiifbm","ogeo","gicjog","cjnibenelm","ogoloc","edciifkaff","kbeeg","nebn","jdd","aeojhclmdn","dilbhl","dkk","bgmck","ohgkefkadonafg","labem","fheoglj","gkcanacfjfhogjc","eglkcddd","lelelihakeh","hhjijfiodfi","enehbibnhfjd","gkm","ggj","ag","hhhjogk","lllicdhihn","goakjjnk","lhbn","fhheedadamlnedh","bin","cl","ggjljjjf","fdcdaobhlhgj","nijlf","i","gaemagobjfc","dg","g","jhlelodgeekj","hcimohlni","fdoiohikhacgb","k","doiaigclm","bdfaoncbhfkdbjd","f","jaikbciac","cjgadmfoodmba","molokllh","gfkngeebnggo","lahd","n","ehfngoc","lejfcee","kofhmoh","cgda","de","kljnicikjeh","edomdbibhif","jehdkgmmofihdi","hifcjkloebel","gcghgbemjege","kobhhefbbb","aaikgaolhllhlm","akg","kmmikgkhnn","dnamfhaf","mjhj","ifadcgmgjaa","acnjehgkflgkd","bjj","maihjn","ojakklhl","ign","jhd","kndkhbebgh","amljjfeahcdlfdg","fnboolobch","gcclgcoaojc","kfokbbkllmcd","fec","dljma","noa","cfjie","fohhemkka","bfaldajf","nbk","kmbnjoalnhki","ccieabbnlhbjmj","nmacelialookal","hdlefnbmgklo","bfbblofk","doohocnadd","klmed","e","hkkcmbljlojkghm","jjiadlgf","ogadjhambjikce","bglghjndlk","gackokkbhj","oofohdogb","leiolllnjj","edekdnibja","gjhglilocif","ccfnfjalchc","gl","ihee","cfgccdmecem","mdmcdgjelhgk","laboglchdhbk","ajmiim","cebhalkngloae","hgohednmkahdi","ddiecjnkmgbbei","ajaengmcdlbk","kgg","ndchkjdn","heklaamafiomea","ehg","imelcifnhkae","hcgadilb","elndjcodnhcc","nkjd","gjnfkogkjeobo","eolega","lm","jddfkfbbbhia","cddmfeckheeo","bfnmaalmjdb","fbcg","ko","mojfj","kk","bbljjnnikdhg","l","calbc","mkekn","ejlhdk","hkebdiebecf","emhelbbda","mlba","ckjmih","odfacclfl","lgfjjbgookmnoe","begnkogf","gakojeblk","bfflcmdko","cfdclljcg","ho","fo","acmi","oemknmffgcio","mlkhk","kfhkndmdojhidg","ckfcibmnikn","dgoecamdliaeeoa","ocealkbbec","kbmmihb","ncikad","hi","nccjbnldneijc","hgiccigeehmdl","dlfmjhmioa","kmff","gfhkd","okiamg","ekdbamm","fc","neg","cfmo","ccgahikbbl","khhoc","elbg","cbghbacjbfm","jkagbmfgemjfg","ijceidhhajmja","imibemhdg","ja","idkfd","ndogdkjjkf","fhic","ooajkki","fdnjhh","ba","jdlnidngkfffbmi","jddjfnnjoidcnm","kghljjikbacd","idllbbn","d","mgkajbnjedeiee","fbllleanknmoomb","lom","kofjmmjm","mcdlbglonin","gcnboanh","fggii","fdkbmic","bbiln","cdjcjhonjgiagkb","kooenbeoongcle","cecnlfbaanckdkj","fejlmog","fanekdneoaammb","maojbcegdamn","bcmanmjdeabdo","amloj","adgoej","jh","fhf","cogdljlgek","o","joeiajlioggj","oncal","lbgg","elainnbffk","hbdi","femcanllndoh","ke","hmib","nagfahhljh","ibifdlfeechcbal","knec","oegfcghlgalcnno","abiefmjldmln","mlfglgni","jkofhjeb","ifjbneblfldjel","nahhcimkjhjgb","cdgkbn","nnklfbeecgedie","gmllmjbodhgllc","hogollongjo","fmoinacebll","fkngbganmh","jgdblmhlmfij","fkkdjknahamcfb","aieakdokibj","hddlcdiailhd","iajhmg","jenocgo","embdib","dghbmljjogka","bahcggjgmlf","fb","jldkcfom","mfi","kdkke","odhbl","jin","kcjmkggcmnami","kofig","bid","ohnohi","fcbojdgoaoa","dj","ifkbmbod","dhdedohlghk","nmkeakohicfdjf","ahbifnnoaldgbj","egldeibiinoac","iehfhjjjmil","bmeimi","ombngooicknel","lfdkngobmik","ifjcjkfnmgjcnmi","fmf","aoeaa","an","ffgddcjblehhggo","hijfdcchdilcl","hacbaamkhblnkk","najefebghcbkjfl","hcnnlogjfmmjcma","njgcogemlnohl","ihejh","ej","ofn","ggcklj","omah","hg","obk","giig","cklna","lihaiollfnem","ionlnlhjckf","cfdlijnmgjoebl","dloehimen","acggkacahfhkdne","iecd","gn","odgbnalk","ahfhcd","dghlag","bchfe","dldblmnbifnmlo","cffhbijal","dbddifnojfibha","mhh","cjjol","fed","bhcnf","ciiibbedklnnk","ikniooicmm","ejf","ammeennkcdgbjco","jmhmd","cek","bjbhcmda","kfjmhbf","chjmmnea","ifccifn","naedmco","iohchafbega","kjejfhbco","anlhhhhg"]

```
output: false. Expected: true.
```

Comment: The failing test is ridiculously long.

Comment: Why can't you check s.contains(dictItems) instead?

Answer (score 0):

You should test till the end. Your method returns immediatly after the first part matches (`return wordBreak` ... ) but there could be different matchings with other start words. 
E.g. you test **aabaa** and your dict is **[aa, aab]** then your method would return `false` because **aa** is found first and **baa** is not within `dict`.

You have to test all combinations. Change your method to

```
public boolean wordBreak(String s, Set<String> dict) {
    if (dict.contains(s)) {
        return true;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (dict.contains(s.substring(0, i))) {
            //Here is the modification:
            if (wordBreak(s.substring(i), dict))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You see, it returns only if the recursive call of wordBreak succeeds and not in every case.